# If I change my laptop from Windows 10s to win 10 will I be able to run normal pc games/programs;like stardew valley?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gaming

I recently purchased a hp laptop for playing the updated of version of stardew valley.The laptop runs on Win10s,the game is not compatible,apparently because it's 10s,not win10. I am not tech savvy at all.I can remove the"s"from the windows but it's permanent.Idk if it will fix it.

Comment: If you are given the option to uninstall or modify your installation to Windows 10, provided you have a supported processor, you will indeed be able to run x86 desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the "S" itself that's stopping you. Windows 10S is a different operating system from Windows 10. It is a different license, and it has different hardware requirements.

If your computer has the correct type of hardware to support actual Windows 10, you will be able to upgrade the license and OS type to support the full Windows 10. To make this change you go to Settings > Updates and Security > Activation. You'll see an option to change your license type: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switching-out-of-s-mode-in-windows-10-4f56d9be-99ec-6983-119f-031bfb28a307

If your computer hardware is not the correct type to support Windows 10 you will not be able to do this.

Whether your computer will support the game after depends on details you have not provided in your question.